# How can I do callback in ui dialog

Tags: jquery, asp.net, .net, jquery-ui

I have two pages.  One of is main.aspx, another one is register.aspx.

Register page loaded with ui dialog in main.aspx.  I used callback two pages.  Main.aspx work normally but I load register.aspx, main.aspx use register's callback and raisecallback function :\

How can we fix this :)

Comment: Try to explain your question better, also put some code sample to help

Comment: I don't understand this, can you try to explain it better?

Comment: In main page I have a lot of functions and they works normally at first(because all of them use main.aspx.cs 's raise callback functions).I have register button in main page then I click it then opening register.aspx(I import it with load('register.aspx') function) in pop up(ui dialog) this page works normally(it use register.aspx.cs 's raisecallback function).And I close the pop up then all main page functions cant work because they use register.aspx.cs 's raisecallback function now.Whats my mistake :\

Answer (score 0):

Create child controls for both register and main page. Add both these in another page. Now use your callbacks they will work fine now.